# REST API composite query: How do I use the result of a query subrequest in the referenceId of another subrequest?

Tags: rest-api, composite

I am using Salesforce's REST API to (1) retrieve a list of object IDs according to a query, then (2) retrieve the records that correlate to those IDs.  I am familiar with the Salesforce composite documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite.htm).

My request looks like this:

```
POST: /services/data/v48.0/composite

{
    "allOrNone":false,
    "compositeRequest": [ {
        "method":"GET",
        "url": "/services/data/v48.0/query?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+My_Entity+WHERE+(CreatedById+!=+'asdfghjkl')",
        "referenceId": "myEntity"
        },{
        "method":"GET",
        "url": "/services/data/v48.0/composite/sobjects/My_Entity?ids=@{myEntity.records[0].Id}",
        "referenceId":"myObject"
    }]
}
```

My response:

```
{
    "compositeResponse" : [ {
        "body" : {
            "totalSize" : 21,
            "done" : true,
            "records" : [ {
                "attributes" : {
                    "type" : "My_Entity",
                    "url" : "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/My_Entity/a0D6g000xxxxxxx"
                },
                "Id" : "a0D6g000xxxxxxx"
                }, {*record2*}, {*etc*}
            ]},
            "httpHeaders" : { },
            "httpStatusCode" : 200,
            "referenceId" : "myEntity"
        }, {
        "body" : [ {
        "errorCode" : "PROCESSING_HALTED",
        "message" : "'myEntity.records' references an invalid Datatype. Only Strings and primitive data types are allowed to be referenced from previous operations."
        } ],
        "httpHeaders" : { },
        "httpStatusCode" : 400,
        "referenceId" : "myObject"
    } ]
}
```

The first subrequest (the query) executes without errors.  My problem is the second subrequest.  I understand from [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/requests_composite.htm) that I can refer to the ID of a single item (e.g. `myEntity.records[0].Id`).  **Question: How do I use all items from `myEntity.records` in the second subrequest?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The indexing of (a list of) referenced records is relative to the `body` key, the expected syntax is `@{<reference>.records[x].<field>}`. Here's a working request:

POST to `/services/data/v48.0/composite`

```js
{
    "allOrNone":false,
    "compositeRequest": [ {
        "method":"GET",
        "url": "/services/data/v48.0/query?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+Account",
        "referenceId": "accts"
        },{
        "method":"GET",
        "url": "/services/data/v48.0/query?q=SELECT+Name+FROM+Account+WHERE+Id='@{accts.records[0].Id}'",
        "referenceId":"myObject"
    }]
}
```

Response with redacted IDs:

```js
{
   "compositeResponse": [
      {
         "body":
         {
            "totalSize": ...,
            "done": true,
            "records": [
               {
                  "attributes":
                  {
                     "type": "Account",
                     "url": "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Account/001..."
                  },
                  "Id": "001..."
               }
            ]
         },
         "httpHeaders": {},
         "httpStatusCode": 200,
         "referenceId": "accts"
      },
      {
         "body":
         {
            "totalSize": 1,
            "done": true,
            "records": [
               {
                  "attributes":
                  {
                     "type": "Account",
                     "url": "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Account/001..."
                  },
                  "Name": "Some Account Name"
               }
            ]
         },
         "httpHeaders": {},
         "httpStatusCode": 200,
         "referenceId": "myObject"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer!  I understand that `@{<reference>.records[x].<field>}` is the correct syntax.  However, I would like to use _all_ record items in my second subrequest, not just the first item in the list.  Does this mean that I need to have multiple subrequests, each hardcoded with an index?  (i.e. `@{accts.records[0].Id}`, `@{accts.records[1].Id}`, `@{accts.records[2].Id}`, etc)

Comment: Oops, pardon for less than helpful answer. Unfortunately there's no way to do this out of the box, it won't do a join of values across records for you. You could create a custom Apex REST service or you can do a join on the client side and then issue another request..

Comment: Darn, that is disappointing to hear.  Ah well.  Thank you for clarifying! :)