# Rest API - Returning Newly Created Fields on Create (POST)

Tags: rest-api

I have an application that is creating a Salesforce Case via the API (POST on /services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Case/). This application is expected to return the case number to the user. Therefore, the application does a GET with the Case ID returned from the POST to get the details.

Is there a way to instruct the POST request to return more fields other than the ID?

Comment: No - use the [Composite](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301873/rest-api-composite-query-how-do-i-use-the-result-of-a-query-subrequest-in-the-r/) resource

Comment: You can also create a HttpResource

Answer (score -1):

Salesforce SOAP or REST api doesn't support the feature you are looking for. If this is must, you can build custom rest api in rest where you can query newly created case and return case number.